# deployed Express js app to Vercel results in error regarding static files

Tags: express, vercel

So I finally wanted to upload my app to Vercel, so I started doing it, but encountered this error: The express.static ("./public) doesn't work. Sorry it's not that it doesn't work it's just that I don't know how to explain it correctly. This is my server.js:

```
//npm install websocket
var WebSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

var path = require('path');

http.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 5000');
});


app.use("/", express.static("./public"))


io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log(socket.id)
})

var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: http,
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

var msg = "null";

wsServer.on('request', function (request) {
  //console.log(request)

  var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin)
  if (connection.remoteAddresses[0] === "random ip") {

    connection.on('message', function (message) {
      if (message.type === 'utf8') {
        if (message.utf8Data !== "/") {
          console.log(message.utf8Data);
          msg = message.utf8Data
        } else {
          connection.sendUTF(msg);
          console.log("esp 32" + msg)
        }

      }
      else if (message.type === 'binary') {
        console.log('Received Binary Message of ' + message.binaryData.length + ' bytes');
        connection.sendBytes(message.binaryData);
      }
    });



    connection.on('close', function (reasonCode, description) {
      console.log(' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
    });
  }
});
```

And this is the vercel.json:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "name": "esp-test",## Heading ##
    "installCommand": "npm install",
    "buildCommand": "npm start",
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "/server.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        },
        {
            "src": "public/**",
            "use": "@vercel/static"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "server.js"
        },
        {
            "src": "/",
            "dest": "public/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

I followed some code regarding this other post but I still don't know what it's wrong. The post: [Deploy an Express server that uses express.static to serve a build folder to Vercel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133185/deploy-an-express-server-that-uses-express-static-to-serve-a-build-folder-to-ver)

If anybody can help me, I'd be really thankful, Thanks once again